# How to create profile for logged in users from the database?

Tags: php, yii2-basic-app

I am working under yii2 basic i created login form with the database i want to display the details of logged in users from the database.

Pls anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created profile page.

**Controller code:**

```
public function actionProfile1()
{
    //if (isset($_POST['formdata'])) {

    $employee_id=$_POST['employee_id'];
    $employee_name=$_POST['employee_name'];
    $email_id=$_POST['email_id'];

    $joining_date=$_POST['joining_date'];
    $joining=  date('d-M-Y',strtotime($joining_date));
    $confirmation_date=$_POST['confirmation_date'];
    $relieving_date=$_POST['relieving_date'];
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE Employee SET Name='$employee_name', Email_id='$email_id 'where Employee_id='$employee_id' ")->execute();

    $model = new Employee();
    $query = Employee::find()->all();
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Updated Successfully');
    return $this->render('profile', [
        'model' => $model,
        'Employee' => $query,
    ]); 
}
```

And add in view to identify the user:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->Email_id;
```